# Code Changes for Implementing Kubernetes Probes

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, .net-core, livenessprobe

I want to implement Kubernetes Liveliness Probes in my .Net core application with C# language. I understood that first I need to define the liveliness probe in deployment.yaml file of my application. I also created the http service in my application that is responding at 8080 port.

[image]

Apart from this what changes do I need to do in my C# code ? I am using below Kubernetes nuget in .csproj :

```
<PackageReference Include="KubernetesClient" Version="3.0.7" />
```

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/deploying-asp-net-core-applications-to-kubernetes-part-6-adding-health-checks-with-liveness-readiness-and-startup-probes/

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/deploying-asp-net-core-applications-to-kubernetes-part-6-adding-health-checks-with-liveness-readiness-and-startup-probes/#health-checks-in-asp-net-core is alternative to deployment.yml liveliness probe or with deployment.yml definition , this too need to be implemented ?

Comment: yml file is only declaration for k8s how to check readiness, liveness of your application. It's your responsibility to implement them in application.

Comment: AFAIK regarding `KubernetesClient` - it's a client to communicate with k8s itself (you can get pods or services in `dotnet` application). It won't implement health checks for your application automatically.